# Is reference always a better choice in c++

Tags: c++, performance, reference

```
std::set<BigObject> set;
auto it = set.begin();
auto& it = set.begin();
```

Similarly,

```
std::string str("xxxxxxxxx");
std::string sub = str.substr(xx);
std::string& sub = str.substr(xx);
```

Will the time desctructor called decrease by using reference? And why?

Comment: That code isn't valid, you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference (unless you use Visual C++, which doesn't obey that rule by default)

Comment: If you used a reference-to-const, the code would become valid. Now, assuming you did that (which is not really an potion for normal iterator use) the compiler could still elide the copy construction easily, making both variants equally performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By value is the best choice when it is applicable and you can afford copying.

The reason is that value semantics are easily understood (behaves like an `int`) and less error prone than references and pointers.

Optimizers have hard time when dealing with pointers and references because these can alias (point to the same objects) or those objects can be referred to from other threads, so that some important optimizations cannot be applied. See [Chandler Carruth: Optimizing the Emergent Structures of C++](http://youtu.be/eR34r7HOU14) for more details.